# Running shell commands in parallel using dask distributed

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have a folder with a lot of .sh scripts. How can I use an already set up dask distributed cluster to run them in parallel?

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
import dask, distributed, os

# list with shell commands that I want to run
commands = ['./script1.sh', './script2.sh', './script3.sh']

# delayed function used to execute a command on a worker
run_func = dask.delayed(os.system)

# connect to cluster
c = distributed.Client('my_server:8786')

# submit job
futures = c.compute( [run_func(c) for c in commands])

# keep connection alive, do not exit python
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

This works, however for this scenario it would be ideal if the client could disconnect without causing the scheduler to cancel the job. I am looking for a way to compute my tasks that does not require an active client connection. How could this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.fire_and_forget ? That would be a way to ensure that some task runs on the cluster after the client has gone.

Note also that you have functions like [`wait()`](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.wait) or even `gather()` so you don't need sleep-forever loops.

In general, though, [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) will launch a child process and *not* wait for it to finish, so you don't even need anything complex from dask, since it doesn't appear you are interested in any output from the call.

Comment: I just figured out `fire_and_forget` is also nicely documented here: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html#fire-and-forget